# Remove autocomplete from a SELECT with HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with the autocomplete in HTML, I'd like to remove it from a SELECT in a web page, so it doesn't appear over the page:

[image]

This is  what I want because I'm printing the result in the bottom.

[image]

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="nameSearch" name="nameSearch" onkeyup="searchInput(this.value)">
    <div id="searchOutput"></div>
</form>
```

I tried to add the autocomplete tag, but it works only with the INPUT tag.

`<input autocomplete="off">`

Comment: `autocomplete` should work for input tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Prevent autocomplete a field:

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="nameSearch" autocomplete="false" name="nameSearch" onkeyup="searchInput(this.value)">
<div id="searchOutput"></div>
</form>
```